# How can I reduce this amount of space in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reduce space between about and drop downbox. I tried but ckouldnt.

Here is Css File :https://glory-textile.web.app/css/theme.css
Here is website link : https://glory-textile.web.app

Please help me , Suggestion and any kind of help will be apprecieted

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove
`top: 99%`
from

```
nav .navigation-main .floating-menu > ul > li .navbar-dropdown
```

Answer (score 3):

insert in css style this code

```
.navbar-dropdown {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend use the bootstrap flex navbar. It is very good to understand.